# K means - Add X and Y to a list

Tags: java

I am working on K-means and I need to implement a method that add a point to the data. So a point is composed of 2 elements which are X and Y. Then, my method is the following:

```
  public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
    List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

So I am using an ArrayList to store every points because I think it's more efficient but I do not know how to store x and y together as a single element of the ArrayList. Thank you!

Comment: What is `Data`? That should hold x and y.

Comment: Yes, holding the coordinate of each new points added so X and Y

Comment: then create a new instance of Data, put x and y in there, then store the instance in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Your class called `Data` should be a Value Object that holds the values of both `x` and `y`.

For example:

```
public class Data{
   private int x;
   private int y;
   public Data(final int x, final int y){
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
   }
   public int getX(){
    return this.x;
   }
   public int getY(){
    return this.y;
   }
   public void setX(final int x){
     this.x = x;
   }
   public void setY(final int y){
     this.y = y;
   }
}
```

To add an element to the `ArrayList`, simply instantiate a new `Data` object to add to the `ArrayList`.

```
list.add(new Data(0, 2));//x-coordinate is 0 and y-coordinate is 2
```

If you can not have any paramters in the constructor, you can instantiate a new `Data` object, set the x and y values manually, and then add it to the ArrayList.

```
final Data d = new Data();
d.setX(0);
d.setY(2);
list.add(d);
```

The constructor for `Data` would then look like:

```
public Data(){}
```

Comment: Your answer is nice, so just for completness. @Tom1999 is creating new list inside method without returning type, so any adding to new creating list would be pointless. Please update your answer with return type of `addPoint` method

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's nice but I also can not have arguments in the constructor. So the constructor should be "public Data()"

Comment: @Tom1999 No problem.

Comment: What can be a way to avoid to set the x and y values manually? I can actually have parameters in my addPoint method

Comment: @Tom1999 You could change that to one method invocation, e.g. `d.setXAndY(0, 2)`, but the easiest way is to use the constructor.